# SQL Query - Want to build column based on the values in another column and then use the column to do a left join to get other values

Tags: sql

I am working on building an SQL Query where the following tables are available. The Manager and reportee table where the relationship of the manager and reportee is maintained

```
Person      Subordinate
A            A1
A1           A2
A2               A3
A3               A4

Person      Designation
A       Senior Manager
A1      Manager
A2      Deputy Manager
A3      Assistant Manager
A4      Officer

Designation     Work
Senior Manager      X1
Senior Manager      X2
Manager     X3
Deputy Manager  X4
Deputy Manager  X5
```

I have written the query which merges table 1 and table 2 as under:

```
SELECT 
    table1.person AS 'LEVEL_1', table1.subordinate AS 'LEVEL_2', 
    table2.subordinate AS 'LEVEL_3', table3.subordiante AS 'LEVEL_4', 
    table4.subordinate AS 'LEVEL_5', table5.subordinate AS 'LEVEL_6' 
FROM  
    employee_hierarchy table1
LEFT JOIN 
    employee_hierarchy table2 ON table2.person = table1.subordinate
LEFT JOIN 
    employee_hierarchy table3 ON table3.person = table2.subordinate
LEFT JOIN 
    employee_hierarchy table4 ON table4.person = table3.subordinate
LEFT JOIN 
    employee_hierarchy table5 ON table5.person = table4.subordinate
ORDER BY 
    LEVEL_1, LEVEL_2, LEVEL_3, LEVEL_4, LEVEL_5
```

I want to get the work details against the employee in the lowest level. Can someone help?

Comment: please share output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am changing my answer after seeing your last comment. What I have understood is you want to have work information for Level_2 column. Try this:

```
with cte as (
SELECT 
    table1.person AS 'LEVEL_1', table1.Subordinate AS 'LEVEL_2', 
    table2.subordinate AS 'LEVEL_3', table3.Subordinate AS 'LEVEL_4', 
    table4.subordinate AS 'LEVEL_5', table5.Subordinate AS 'LEVEL_6' 
FROM  
    employee_hierarchy table1
LEFT JOIN 
    employee_hierarchy table2 ON table2.person = table1.subordinate
LEFT JOIN 
    employee_hierarchy table3 ON table3.person = table2.subordinate
LEFT JOIN 
    employee_hierarchy table4 ON table4.person = table3.subordinate
LEFT JOIN 
    employee_hierarchy table5 ON table5.person = table4.subordinate
    )
    select level_1,level_2,level_3,level_4,level_5,employee.designation,workdetails.work from cte inner join employee 
    on level_2=employee.person
           left join workdetails on employee.designation=workdetails.designation
           ORDER BY     LEVEL_1, LEVEL_2, LEVEL_3, LEVEL_4, LEVEL_5
```

[image]
Hope this will be your desired query:

```
with cte as (
SELECT 
    table1.person AS 'LEVEL_1', table1.Subordinate AS 'LEVEL_2', 
    table2.subordinate AS 'LEVEL_3', table3.Subordinate AS 'LEVEL_4', 
    table4.subordinate AS 'LEVEL_5', table5.Subordinate AS 'LEVEL_6' 
FROM  
    employee_hierarchy table1
LEFT JOIN 
    employee_hierarchy table2 ON table2.person = table1.subordinate
LEFT JOIN 
    employee_hierarchy table3 ON table3.person = table2.subordinate
LEFT JOIN 
    employee_hierarchy table4 ON table4.person = table3.subordinate
LEFT JOIN 
    employee_hierarchy table5 ON table5.person = table4.subordinate
    )
    select level_1,level_2,level_3,level_4,level_5,employee.designation,workdetails.work from cte inner join employee 
    on (case when level_6 is not null then cte.level_6 when level_5 is not null then level_5 when level_4 is not null then level_4
           when level_3 is not null then level_3 when level_2 is not null then level_2 when level_1 is not null then level_1 end)=employee.person
           left join workdetails on employee.designation=workdetails.designation
```

[image]

Comment: The expected output should look like this: Person Subordinate1 Subordinate2  Subordinate3 Subordinate4  Designation
A A1  A2  A3  A4  Officer (A4)
A1 A2  A3  A4  Null  Officer (A4)
A2      A3  A4  Null  Null  Officer (A4)
A3      A4  Null  Null  Null  Officer (A4)

Comment: -Bro...I am able to build the hierarchy table wherein in a single row I am able to plot all the subordinates for a person, but I am facing a challenge as I want the designation of the person who is the lowest in the hierarchy in a particular row. Hope I am able to convey my requirements. So I want to build a column which captures the last occurring value in either from LEVEL 1 to LEVEL 5 and get the corresponding value against such value from another table though a left join

Comment: Sorry I goofed up.... The result of my query is A --- A1---- Null ---- Null ---- Null in row 1, A --- A1 ---- A2 ---- Null ---- Null in row 2, A --- A1 ---- A2 ---- A3 --- Null in row 3 . I want to put a new column where I can capture the Work Information for the last person in every row.... Here in my case it is A1 in first row, A2 in second row, A3 in third row